# Cabal install error /usr/bin/ld: --hash-size=31: unknown option

Tags: ld, ghc, cabal, binutils, gold-linker

When trying to install any package on my computer using a command like

```
cabal install http-conduit
```

the installation aborts with the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: --hash-size=31: unknown option
```

How can I resolve this?

*Note:* This question intentionally doesn't show research effort, because it was answered immediately in a Q&A-Style manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue occurs with the *binutils-gold* package and GHC 7.4. There is an old [mailing list entry](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2011-December/097962.html) discussing this issue.

You might need *binutils-gold* for LLVM for example, but GHC 7.4 can't handle the GOLD linker correctly, because it doesn't understand the `--hash-size` option.

As noted on the mailing list post, the solution to this is to remove *binutils-gold*, e.g. on Ubuntu use:

```
sudo apt-get remove binutils-gold
```

This will re-symlink `/usr/bin/ld` to a non-GOLD linker version. After that, repeat the `cabal install`  command.

Comment: [GHC can now use `gold` for linking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43243322/how-to-link-with-the-gnu-gold-linker-instead-of-ld-in-haskell/) and will not pass the problematic `--hash-size` flag when told to use gold.