# How to link with the GNU gold linker instead of ld in Haskell

Tags: haskell, linker, gold-linker

My Haskell project spends lots of time in `Linking dist/build/myapp/myapp ...` and also in loading shared libraries when executing `TemplateHaskell` code.

I suspect this is because `ld` is slow.

How can I improve link times by switching to the `gold` linker?

Comment: Besides switching linker you could use `-dynamic` flag. It could easily speedup linking tenfold.

Comment: @vshabanov Is this actually the case? I have tried in the past to use dynamic linking and it did not make things faster for my entire cabal project. But I may have done something wrong so that it used `-dynamic-too`, giving me both static and dynamic libraries. It would be great to have a minimal example project that shows if it really makes it faster.

Comment: you should use only `-dynamic` GHC option. `-dynamic-too` links **both** statically (slow, large executables) and dynamically (smaller executables, faster link times), so you don't get any speedup.

Comment: @vshabanov I've tried dynamically linked executables now, they are not a good choice for me, because the startup time of my executable (just for the `--help` text) increased from `160 ms` (static) to `4.5 seconds` due to run-time linking. I will stick with static linking for now.

Comment: That's quite strange (both 0.16s and 4.5s for app start). What platform you're on? And do you have enough free RAM? Perhaps long linking you have is a cache issue. And interesting what was linking speedup on your projects when you tried dynamic linking?

Comment: @vshabanov On Linux. I have about 30 GB free RAM. It's not a cache issue, it happens on subsequent starts; the time it takes is 100% user CPU time spent in the ld-linux dynamic linker/loader. [This page](https://www.iecc.com/linker/linker10.html) agrees with the phenomenon: `The runtime performance costs of dynamic linking are substantial compared to those of static linking`. Note I have 100s of entries in `lld`. Regarding speedup, link time seems to have gone down from 2.5 s per executable to 1.5, but that's not worth the increased startup time for me.

Comment: I found [this useful comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1607954/263061) that suggests that dynamic linking speed can be drastically improved by setting `-fvisibility=hidden` and manually exporting all exported symbols. Maybe the dynamic loading startup time could be improved by using that.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

## Link 3x faster with `gold`

[Since GHC 7.8](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/6063), you can tell GHC and cabal (at run time without having to recompile GHC) to link with GNU gold.

You need in your `.cabal` file:

```
library:
  ghc-options: -optl-fuse-ld=gold
  ld-options:  -fuse-ld=gold

executable myExecutable
  ghc-options: -optl-fuse-ld=gold
  ld-options:  -fuse-ld=gold
```

(Note you might want to pass these flags to `stack`/`cabal`/`Setup.hs` on the command line instead of hardcoding them in the .cabal file in order to not reduce the portability of the package.)

For me it's `3.5x` faster, bringing down the total link time of a project from 150 seconds to 40 seconds.

---

## Update: Link 10x faster with `lld`

See https://github.com/nh2/link-with-lld-example for a full example; key parts:

```
library
  ghc-options: "-pgmP clang" "-pgmc clang" "-pgma clang" "-pgml clang" "-optl-fuse-ld=lld"
  ld-options:  -fuse-ld=lld

executable myExecutable
  ghc-options: "-pgmP clang" "-pgmc clang" "-pgma clang" "-pgml clang"
  ld-options:  -fuse-ld=lld
```

Comparison of link time for the final executable link times my project:

```
ld   124 seconds
gold  36 seconds
lld   11 seconds
```

Comment: How big is your project, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @jberryman Not very big, 150 Haskell modules and 8 executables built from them. But it depends on (and links) a couple native libraries like opencv. With `ld`, each library link takes almost 20 seconds.

Comment: Confirming build speed up by reducing time by `40` seconds on 489 modules and 13 executables project (tests and benchmakrs included).

Comment: @SebastianGraf It does not work out of the box with `lld`, at least not with the options I provided, because (at least on my system) ghc links by calling `gcc`, and gcc is [not (yet) compatible with `lld`](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2016-07/msg00155.html). You would have to tell ghc to use the clang toolchain instead of gcc; I haven't tried that yet. Would be very interested to know what the flags are for that though.

Comment: Wow, that's awesome! Let's start a GHC proposal to use `lld` by default!

Comment: Will it work without changes to the .cabal if you simply overwrite the /usr/bin/ld symlink to ldd?

Comment: @unhammer It will not necessarily work; `lld` doesn't accept all flags that `ld` accepts, and officially `gcc` (which GHC invokes by default for linking) doesn't support linking with `lld`. (Also you mean `lld`, not `ldd` -- just saying because this typo can actually get confusing, as both are linking related programs).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @nh2 – and yes, I've already confused myself with the typo many times :)

Comment: @nh2 it looks like `-fuse-ld=lld` is supported now (at lease as of ghc 10; just tried it. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83243). I wonder how that changes things? Can those `ghc-options` go away now?

Comment: @jberryman I think you mean `gcc 10` instead of `ghc 10`? I will need to check what can be removed now, but haven't had time yet. Also there's already a new, even faster linker available now: [mold](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Mold-1.0-Released).